# Gymnastics with Set Operations for Probability Events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

> $\textbf{The Problem:}$ Let $A_1,\dots,A_5$ be events on the same probability space. Express the following events using the usual set operations $\left(^\complement,\bigcap,\bigcup\right)$ and the events $A_k$ for $1\leq k\leq 5.$
>
> $\textbf{a)}$ None of the five events $A_k$ for $1\leq k\leq 5$ occur.

Using De Morgan's Law, this event can be expressed as
$$\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^5 A_k\right)^\complement=\bigcap_{k=1}^5 A_k^\complement.$$

> $\textbf{b)}$ At least two of the five events $A_k$ for $1\leq k\leq 5$ occur.

For this event, I think that we can express it as
$$\bigcup_{k\in\mathcal P}A_k\quad\quad\quad\text{for some $\mathcal P\subset\mathbb\{1,\dots,5\}$ with $\#\mathcal P=2.$}$$

> $\textbf{c)}$ One or three of the five events $A_k$ for $1\leq k\leq 5$ occur.

For this part, my attempt looks like
$$A_j\cup\left(\bigcup_{k\in\mathcal P}A_k\right)\cup\left(\bigcup_{i\ne j,i\notin\mathcal P}A_i\right)\quad\text{where }j\in\{1,\dots,5\},\mathcal P\subset\{1,\dots,5\}\text{ with }\#\mathcal P=3.$$

---

Could anyone please provide some feedback on my attempted solutions? I am very confident about the first one, but slightly confused about the other two.

Any feedback is much appreciated, and I want to thank you for your time, and wish you a great weekend.

Comment: (b) sounds wrong to my ear., might be fixable by replacing the $\cup$ with a $\cap$ instead.  It is also unusual to see $\mathcal{P}$ used for that purpose.  I would instead have written something more along the lines of $\bigcup\limits_{I\in\binom{[5]}{2}}\bigcap\limits_{i\in I} A_i$, here using the notation that $[5]=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $\binom{N}{k}$ with $N$ a set is the set of subsets of $N$ of size $k$.

Comment: For (c), this sure feels cumbersome to write... but we need somehow to get across that for the case of $3$ events occurring that not only must those three events occur but also that the remaining two do *not* occur... So, something like $\bigcup\limits_{I\in(\binom{[5]}{1}\cup\binom{[5]}{3})}\left(\bigcap\limits_{i\in I}A_i\cap \bigcap\limits_{i\in [5]\setminus I}A_i^c\right)$